# Graphs: figure out if the path is at least X% better than others

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, path

Assume we have a path in an undirected cyclic weighted graph. Assuming we have an engine that can find a path from node A to node B in such a graph, is there an easy way/algorithm to figure out if the given path from A to B is at least X% better than any other disjoint path from A to B? By disjoint I mean two paths may not share any edges.

Comment: Could you define "X% better"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see to do this is to remove the edges of the given path from the graph, find a [minimum weight path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) from A to B in the smaller graph, and compare.

To solve this problem using this approach, try one of these well-studied algorithms:

- Dijkstra's algorithm solves the single-source shortest path problems.
- Bellman-Ford algorithm solves the single source problem if edge weights may be negative.
- A* search algorithm solves for single pair shortest path using heuristics to try to speed up the search.
- Floyd-Warshall algorithm solves all pairs shortest paths.
- Johnson's algorithm solves all pairs shortest paths, and may be faster than Floyd-Warshall on sparse graphs.
- Perturbation theory finds (at worst) the locally shortest path.

Comment: This will not work in many cases such as : V={v1,v2,v3,v4}
E={(v1,v2),(v2,v3),(v2,v4)}.
In this case removing the edges from one path will remove the other path.
If you wish to find the second best path (to compare) there is an algorithm for that.

Comment: @Belgi: In what sense does this not work? If removing these edges removes all other paths, then there is no **disjoint** path.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the paths are disjoint in edges (voted u up).

Comment: One interesting suggestion I have which seems helping but I struggle to accept. The suggestion is to increase the weight (or decrease if we are looking for the 'heaviest' path) of all edges of the initial path by X% and run search again. If the resulting path matches the initial one then the initial one is at least X% better than any other. Does it really work? I tried draw pictures and so far I can't say it does NOT work.

Comment: @PengOne: the searching is not an issue - we do have A* based engine.

Comment: @Schultz9999 I do not see how this addresses the *disjoint* property (and I think I just drew a counter-example). I believe it does work if you remove that word, though.

Comment: @PengOne: yes, you are right. I jumped to a bigger issue, which is answering the same question but extending it to such that if a path is A->B->C->D->E->F then none of the subpaths (e.g. B-E and recursively C->D has better alternatives). For such case, I would change the weights of B->C, C->D and D->E and find a A->F path again. If it matches the initial one, it means A->F path is the best by at least X% on any stretch of it.